# Heatmap axis labeling in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I am trying to generate a heatmap of a random matrix with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

data = np.random.rand(7, 7)
ax = sns.heatmap(data)
plt.show()
```

Which gives me:

[image: heatmap]

However I would like for the axis numberings to start at 1 not at 0, how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ax.set_xticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels) and [`ax.set_yticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels.html) to re-label the axes from 1 to 7:

```
import numpy as np                                                              
import seaborn as sns                                                           
import matplotlib.pylab as plt                                                  

data = np.random.rand(7, 7)                                                     
ax = sns.heatmap(data)                                                          
ax.set_xticklabels(range(1, 8))                                                 
ax.set_yticklabels(range(1, 8))                                                 
plt.show()
```

[image]